# Trying to pull specific data from a list of dictionaries in Python. (Using Robin-Stocks)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

So I'm using the robin-stocks api and I'm trying to pull specific data from a provided function.

The output when I print:

`positions = r.crypto.get_crypto_positions()`

is:

```
[{'account_id': 'removed', 'cost_bases': [{'currency_id': 'removed', 'direct_cost_basis': '0.110000000000000000', 'direct_quantity': '0.000011050000000000', 'id': 'removed', 'intraday_quantity': '0.000000000000000000', 'intraday_cost_basis': '0.000000000000000000', 'marked_cost_basis': '0.000000000000000000', 'marked_quantity': '0.000000000000000000'}], 'created_at': '2020-05-07T20:44:23.510080-04:00', 'currency': {'brand_color': 'EA963D', 'code': 'BTC', 'id': 'removed', 'increment': '0.000000010000000000', 'name': 'Bitcoin', 'type': 'cryptocurrency'}, 'id': 'removed', 'quantity': '0.000011050000000000', 'quantity_available': '0.000011050000000000', 'quantity_held_for_buy': '0.000000000000000000', 'quantity_held_for_sell': '0.000000000000000000', 'updated_at': '2020-05-07T23:40:34.381524-04:00'}]
```

This is the documentation on their website regarding this:

`robin_stocks.crypto.get_crypto_positions(info=None)[source]`

Returns crypto positions for the account.

Parameters: info (Optional[str]) – Will filter the results to get a specific value.
Returns:    Returns a list of dictionaries of key/value pairs for each option. If info parameter is provided, a list of strings is returned where the strings are the value of the key that matches info.

My goal here is to get the `'direct_cost_basis'`. How can I achieve this? I'm fairly decent at python however this is just going over my head.

Comment: you have the traverse into the list json  `positions[0]["cost_bases"][0]["direct_cost_basis"]`

Answer (score 0):

`positions` is a list of dicts. You can access the first element in the list with

```
positions[0]
```

The `direct_cost_basis` appears to be in a dict in a list which is keyed by `cost_bases`, which is in the first element of `positions`. Therefore:

```
positions[0]["cost_bases"][0]["direct_cost_basis"]
```

will yield what you want.

As part of your debugging process, while printing something in Python it can be useful to also print the "type" of the object via `type(positions)` which would return `list`. You can use this all the way down to determine how to access these data types. You can also call the function `dir(positions)` on any Python object which will tell you that object's attributes and methods.